# RealSense ROS Pointcloud and RGB Image alignment

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, realsense

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a dog detection system using deep learning (Tensorflow object detection) and Real Sense D425 camera. I am using the Intel(R) RealSense(TM) ROS Wrapper in order to get images from the camera.

I am executing "roslaunch rs_rgbd.launch" and my Python code is subscribed to "/camera/color/image_raw" topic in order to get the RGB image. Using this image and object detection library, I am able to infer (20 fps) the location of a dog in a image as a box level (xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax)

I will like to crop the PointCloud information with the object detection information (xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax) and determine if the dog is far away or near the camera. I will like to use the aligned information pixel by pixel between the RGB image and the pointcloud.

How can I do it? Is there any topic for that?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315476/realsense-ros-pointcloud-and-rgb-image-alignment/) by [aitul](https://answers.ros.org/users/39992/aitul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-02-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kolya_rage](https://answers.ros.org/users/35353/kolya_rage/) on 2019-02-13**:
I'm not sure I understand. You want to project rgb to pcd. Or you want to downscale point cloud somehow?

**Comment by [aitul](https://answers.ros.org/users/39992/aitul/) on 2019-02-13**:
@kolya_rage I want to know the association between a RGB pixel and the pointcloud. For example, if I crop a zone of an RGB image, I will like to have only the information of the pointcloud of the cropped zone.

**Comment by [kolya_rage](https://answers.ros.org/users/35353/kolya_rage/) on 2019-02-13**:
I see. So you should have projection matrix from the realsense camera, don't you?

**Comment by [aitul](https://answers.ros.org/users/39992/aitul/) on 2019-02-13**:
What do you mean with projeciton matrix?With the RGB image I am able to detect if a dog appear on the image, and now with the pointcloud, I will like to determine if the dog is on a specific distance from the camera in order to set an alarm.

**Comment by [kolya_rage](https://answers.ros.org/users/35353/kolya_rage/) on 2019-02-13**:
Your point cloud is produced by the real sense, right?

**Comment by [aitul](https://answers.ros.org/users/39992/aitul/) on 2019-02-13**:
Yes, Real Sense D425 camera and ROS Wrapper

**Comment by [kolya_rage](https://answers.ros.org/users/35353/kolya_rage/) on 2019-02-13**:
https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/wiki/Projection-in-RealSense-SDK-2.0
Here is projection and deprojection api

**Comment by [aitul](https://answers.ros.org/users/39992/aitul/) on 2019-02-13**:
OK, thanks I will have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure this will be any good/efficient but you can directly get the depth for each pixel in the depth image via something like [this](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/2200). (xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax) provide you with all the UV coordinates you need to look for the depth of. There must be a better way, but this would work, and you wouldn't really need the pointcloud even.

Moreover you could check out [q315362](https://answers.ros.org/question/315362), where we were discussing ways of having a pose on the found object, which effectively also gives you the distance of the dog from the camera frame.

---

Originally posted by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) with karma: 589 on 2019-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aitul](https://answers.ros.org/users/39992/aitul/) on 2019-02-13**:
Is there any method or topic to associate each RGB pixel ( "/camera/color/image_raw") with the generated pointcloud?

**Comment by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) on 2019-02-13**:
The pointcloud itself is generated, it gets published [here](https://github.com/intel-ros/realsense/blob/a036d81bcc6890658104a8de1cba24538effd6e3/realsense2_camera/src/base_realsense_node.cpp#L1703). Check [this](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/examples/pointcloud) also.

**Comment by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) on 2019-02-13**:
Found [this](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/jupyter/notebooks/distance_to_object.ipynb) and [this](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/wrappers/opencv/dnn/rs-dnn.cpp), I think you'll like them.

**Comment by [aitul](https://answers.ros.org/users/39992/aitul/) on 2019-02-13**:
Thanks a lot, it looks really nice. I will have a look

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-08-10**:
Pointcloud and depth map are **not** substitutes of each other. This is not an answer to the question. You cannot use depth map for what you use with pointcloud. This question is still an unanswered one, to be honest.

**Comment by [chirag](https://answers.ros.org/users/45199/chirag/) on 2019-08-27**:
Hey! Did you find a solution?
I'm working on the exact some problem.
Getting more specific to my problem, (also addressing other comments on this thread), I know how to find object distance using the pyrealsense python wrapper, but when reading the image data from ROS topic "/camera/color/image_raw", I'm not really launchine the rs pipeline. So, there has to be a way to align the color stream from this topic to the depth data which is being published at another topic (probably "/camera/aligned_depth_to_color" but I'm not sure) and then do distance calculation.
So, is there a way to do that?
Thanks in advance.